# Jquery Resize event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-selectors, jquery-ui-resizable

Can anyone help me in knowing about the resize event handler in jquery. I'm not able to understand the importance of ben-Alman 's jquery resize plugin. I got to know that we can handle resize events of DOM elements using jquery 1.7.1 version  library  and I did an example and getting executed successfully just with jquery library.. Then why is that plugin is used ? Thanking you..

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: Version: 1.1, Last updated: 3/14/2010 ... this plugin is still used there were time stands still.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery resize **only** on window event:

```
$(window).resize(...)
```

Using the plugin you can handle resize event on DOM element you want:

```
$("#id").resize(...)
```